# Error in scala + dispatch

Tags: eclipse, scala, scala-dispatch

I am trying to GET a response from an API, using scala and dispatch. However, I get this error, after building. I googled for a solution, and tried cleaning, and resarting eclipse, but the error wont go away. What seems to be the problem? I use eclipse Helios (ie 3.6) and Scala v2.8.1, with Scala IDE v1.0.0.201104170033, installed from the Eclipse market.

```
dispatch{dispatch.type}.Http{object dispatch.Http} of type object dispatch.Http does not take parameters
```

This is my code.

```
class getList {
  def main(args: Array[String]){
    Http("http://foo.com/" >>> System.out)
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Ingo I honestly forgot to add the code. My apologies.

Comment: I think you may need to declare an instance of Http: `val http=new Http`. Then you can do `http("http://foo.com/" >>> System.out)`, but I don't have scala installed here so I can't test this

Comment: I tried that, it still gives the same error, after clean and build.

Comment: Scala, Eclipse and Eclipse Scala Plugin versions?

Comment: @Daniel added the Scala IDE version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What libraries have you downloaded? Are you sure the dependencies are set correctly? I tried with dispatch_http, version 8.0 for Scala 2.8.1, and it worked.

What imports are you using? I used these imports to make it work:

```
import dispatch.Http
import dispatch.HandlerVerbs._
```

Finally... `class getList`??? I assume this is a result of cut&pasting from actual code, but you should strive to produce a compilable example of your problem. Scala doesn't run programs from `class`, only from `object`, and it follows Java style of having classes start with an uppercase letter.

Here's the minimal code I used with SBT to get a working example.

Initializing:

```
~/test$ sbt
Project does not exist, create new project? (y/N/s) y
Name: test
Organization: test
Version [1.0]: 
Scala version [2.7.7]: 2.8.1
sbt version [0.7.4]:

~/test$ cat project/build/TestProject.scala 
import sbt._

class TestProject(info: ProjectInfo) extends DefaultProject(info) {
  val dvers = "0.8.0"
  val http = "net.databinder" %% "dispatch-http" % dvers
}

~/test$ cat src/main/scala/GetList.scala 
import dispatch.Http
import dispatch.HandlerVerbs._

object GetList {
  def main(args: Array[String]){
    Http("http://foo.com/" >>> System.out)
  }
}

~/test# sbt update run
```

Comment: It turns out that I had missed out on a few libraries. After adding them, I get the response from the API, although it is incomplete.

Comment: Ok.  I was able to build using sbt.  I was able to get Scala version 2.8.1, (although sbt could not find 2.9.0.1) and it ran although it gets [info] == run ==
[info] Running GetList

INF: [console logger] dispatch: foo.com GET / HTTP/1.1

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Serializable
Stemming from: 
   at dispatch.Http.apply(Http.scala:21)
   at GetList$.main(GetList.scala:6)

Comment: @RichMeister You need to specify Scala version as `2.9.0-1` on SBT. Dash instead of dot before the `1`.